# Stretch DIV to the bottom of the page with a element above it

Tags: html, css

I try to stretch a DIV to the bottom of the page with a element above it. That basically works but the height of the element above it is added to the DIV.

Please see jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CjKFX/

How to fix this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#header, #headline { position:absolute; width:100%; top:0; }

#header {height: 100px; z-index:1; background-color:#f40; }
#headline {height: 100%; top:100px; margin-top:-100px; background: #000;}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <header id="header">
            header
        </header>

        <section id="headline">
            section
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zeggw/

​